# Is it possible to cast Json fields when loading them into pig?

Tags: json, casting, apache-pig

I was wondering if there is a way to cast a field that comes in through the `JsonLoader()`. This is basically what I want but it doesn't work.

```
Person = LOAD 'people' USING JsonLoader() AS (name:chararray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with JsonLoader, but i have faced a similar situation with HCatLoader.
There i did the casting in the second line.

```
Person_tmp = LOAD 'people' USING JsonLoader();
Person = FOREACH Person_tmp GENERATE name:chararray;
```

Just try it out. It might work out.

Comment: I've tried that but I get back this error `java.lang.exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.execexception: error 1075: received a bytearray from the udf or union from two different loaders. cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string`